# Regex in python to manage "-"

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that fits with `ready-to-work`, `ready-to-work-today`, `ready-to`. I have been placing the multiple options in this way:

```
text=''' ready-to-work ready-to ready-to-work-today'''

re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-[a-zA-Z0-9]+?-[a-zA-Z0-9]+?\b', text)
```

I have managed to find expressions of up to three terms, such as `['ready-to-work']` but I can not capture `ready-to` and `ready-to-work-today`. I expect `['ready-to-work','ready-to','ready-to-work-today']`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about `r'[\w-]+'` or must there be at least one `-`?

Comment: Your specification is rather imprecise. What exactly do you want it to match to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex `\b\w+(-\w+)+\b`.

Comment: Thanks, but I found: ['-work', '-to', '-today'] ... this is the last word of each term. From what you propose, I did:re.findall(r'\b(\w+[\-\w+]+)\b', text). This throws the result I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: The regex works fine, it's just that you are only pulling out `match.group(1)`.  Add another pair of parentheses around the whole regex, or simply pull out the full match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the hyphen and character class part 1 - 3 times, you could use a non capturing group with a  quantifier `{1,3}`. To match them 1+ times use a `+` instead.

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,3}\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match any of the listed 1+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-[a-zA-Z0-9]+` match`-` and 1+ times any of the listed
- `){1,3}` Close non capturing group and repeat 1-3 times
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6C10qT/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this expression might return the desired output:

```
\b(?:\w+-\w+(?:[\w-])*)\b
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?:\w+-\w+(?:[\w-])*)\b"

test_str = "ready-to-work ready-to-work-today ready-to ready-to-work ready-to ready-to-work-today ready-to ready-to-work-todayready-to ready-to-work-today"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['ready-to-work', 'ready-to-work-today', 'ready-to', 'ready-to-work', 'ready-to', 'ready-to-work-today', 'ready-to', 'ready-to-work-todayready-to', 'ready-to-work-today']
```

#### Demo

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/l3ehn2/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.